# Variable number of decimal places in Excel Graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

My Y-axis in Excel on a log scale currently shows values from 0.0001 to 1000.0000. I wish to edit the number of decimal places so those below zero are decimals yet those above are whole numbers. So the axis would go from 0.0001 to 1000. I am aware of how to increase or decrease decimals places so it is consistent but not how to display either significant figures or vary the amount of decimal places.

[See here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtX5Y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the axis scale using a custom number format like:

```
[<1]0.0000;#,##0
```

This applies the format 0.0000 to values less than 1 and the format 0 (i.e. whole numbers) to all other positive values.